# How to sync to the last version without commiting existing changes?

Tags: git, github

Before I start, I would like to say I am new to git.

Say I have the given scenario:

1. Forked a repo
2. Cloned to my desktop via (Github Windows)
3. Made some changes that I regret (but I added some new files)
4. I want to get the latest files in the repo and override ONLY the files that already exists in the repo. New files should NOT be deleted.

How do I get step 4 done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `git stash` - save your local changes aside
2. `git pull` - pull the latest changes
3. `git stash pop` - apply your local changes from the stack

if you wan't to revert any of your local changes selectively, you can invoke `git checkout $file`

Comment: `if you wan't to revert any of your local changes selectively, you can invoke git checkout $file` what do you mean by that?

Comment: after step 3 (`git stash pop`) you still may want to cancel some  of your local changes you are not satisfied with

Comment: if you want to cancel ALL your changes except the new files, `git checkout root_dir` should work... where `root_dir` is the root directory of the project (it works recursively)